# I cant get another row from table to get login access

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I've copied a login script from a video tutorial which is posted at www.phpacademy.org called "Register & Login"

my login page contains codes below...

---

```
<?php

if (empty($_POST) === false ) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
        $error = '<div id="error" style="font-size:16px; font-family: \'Armata\';">Error: You need to enter <u>Username</u> and <u>Password</u>!</div>';
        }
    else if (user_exists($username) === false){
        $error = '<div id="error" style="font-size:16px; font-family: \'Armata\';">Error: We are not able to get username <u>'.$username.'</u>. Please check your entered details.</div>';
        }
    else if (user_active($username) === false){
        $error = '<div id="error" style="font-size:16px; font-family: \'Armata\';">Error: You need to activate your account by confirming your email address.<br> Check inbox and span folder for confirmation email.</div>';
        }
    else if (strlen($password) > 32 || (strlen($password) < 6 ) ) {
        $error = '<div id="error" style="font-size:16px; font-family: \'Armata\';">Error: Your password must be between 6 and 32 characters.</div>';
    }       
    else {
        $login = login($username, $password);
            if ($login === false) {
            $error = '<div id="error" style="font-size:16px; font-family: \'Armata\';">Error: Your Username or Password is incorrect. Please enter correct details.</div>';
            } else {
                $_SESSION['uid'] = $login;
                header ('Location: /home');
                exit ();
            }

        }
}


?>
```

### and then login form

my login form function page's codes are

---

```
<?php

function sanitize($data) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string($data);
}

function user_data($uid){
        $data = array();
        $uid = (int)$uid;
        $func_num_args = func_num_args();
        $func_get_args = func_get_args();

    if ($func_num_args > 0) {
        unset ($func_get_args[0]);

        $fields = '`' . implode ('`,`',$func_get_args) . '`';
        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `uid` = $uid"));

        return $data;
    }   
}

function user_logged_in() {
    return (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) ? true : false ;
}

function user_exists($username){
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `uid` FROM `users` WHERE `uname` = '$username'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function user_active($username){
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `uid` FROM `users` WHERE `uname` = '$username' AND `active` = 1"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function uid_from_uname($username){
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `uid` FROM `users` WHERE `uname` = '$username' "), 0, 'uid');

}

function login($username, $password){
    $uid = uid_from_uname($username);

    $username = sanitize($username);    
    $password = md5($password);

    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `uid` FROM `users` WHERE `uname` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'"), 0) == 1) ? $uid : false ; 
}

?>
```

---

and in that video they used in query like this "SELECT COUNT (`user_id`)...." which is not working in my system. I am using xampp 1.7.7

The thing is that in first row of my db's table's "id=1", "username=viral.joshi" and "pass=password"

which allows me to enter and not showing me any error, and the second row's data is "id=2", "username=viral4ever" and "pass=password" and when i enter this id pass it shows me error that Cant find username viral4ever.

i edited first row's username and changed it to viral4ever so it allowed me to get access. so please help me to access every rows. My db table's details are "InnoDB"   "latin1_swedish_ci" and columns details username's collation is "utf8_bin" and other's are  "utf8_unicode_ci" and both are varchar acceptable and uid is int. Please anyone help me.

Comment: did password is right ?

Comment: PHP functions that start with `mysql_` have been deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. If you are in a position to do so, please consider updating your code to use the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extensions instead. Find a tutorial newer than 1997.

Comment: You say that your db has the field "id", but in your queries you have "uid". +1 to @Joe F.

Comment: nope, in my db its uid, i just said id as example.

Comment: in my db its uid, i just said id to give example. otherwise it wouldn't work with first row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have improved your code to an updated version. This solution of course assumes that the names of the database table and the columns are correct. In addition you have to replace the 'host', 'user', 'pwd' and 'name' with the real values.

The three following files have to lie within the same directory. I just assume that there is another peace of code that creates and manages the HTML form itself. Preferably you would put that code into the LoginForm as well so that logic and presentation is clearly separated. It won't be a out-of-the-house solution as I don't know the whole picture.

This solution requires that there is an additional column in users named 'salt' (without ') and the passwords are saved in the way used below. md5 is not secure anymore and any tutorial featuring md5 should be ignored right away. This hashing solution utilizes a double salted password and the sha1 hashing algorithm.

The dbconfig.inc.php:

```
<?php
$host = 'host';
$dbUser = 'user';
$dbPwd = 'pwd';
$dbName = 'name';
```

The LoginForm.class.php:

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__.'/LoginDatabase.class.php');

/**
 * Manages the login form..
 * 
 * @author      Jim Martens
 * @copyright   2013 Jim Martens
 * @license     http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-3.0 GNU Lesser General Public License, version 3
 */
class LoginForm {
    /**
     * Contains the login database object.
     * @var \LoginDatabase
     */
    private $loginDatabase = null;

    /**
     * Contains the read username.
     * @var string
     */
    private $username = '';

    /**
     * Contains the read password.
     * @var string
     */
    private $password = '';

    /**
     * Contains the error text.
     * @var string
     */
    private $errorText = '';

    /**
     * Initializes the login form.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->loginDatabase = new \LoginDatabase();
        $this->run();
    }

    /**
     * Reads the form parameters.
     */
    public function readFormParameters() {
        if (isset($_POST['username'])) $this->username = trim($_POST['username']);
        if (isset($_POST['password'])) $this->password = trim($_POST['password']);
    }

    /**
     * Validates the input.
     */
    public function validate() {
        if (empty($this->username) || empty($this->password)) {
            $this->errorText = 'You need to enter <u>Username</u> and <u>Password</u>!';
            throw new \Exception($this->errorText);
        }
        if (!$this->loginDatabase->userExists($this->username)) {
            $this->errorText = 'A user with the username <u>'.$this->username.'</u> doesn\'t exist. Please check your entered details.</div>';
            throw new \Exception($this->errorText);
        }
        if (!$this->loginDatabase->userIsActive($this->username)) {
            $this->errorText = 'You need to activate your account by confirming your email address.<br> Check inbox and span folder for confirmation email.';
            throw new \Exception($this->errorText);
        }
        if (strlen($this->password) > 32 || (strlen($this->password) < 6 ) ) {
            $this->errorText = 'Your password must be between 6 and 32 characters.';
            throw new \Exception($this->errorText);
        }
        if (!$this->loginDatabase->isLoginValid($this->username, $this->password)) {
            $this->errorText = 'You have entered a wrong password.';
            throw new \Exception($this->errorText);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Finishes the login process.
     */
    public function save() {
        $_SESSION['uid'] = $this->loginDatabase->getUserID($this->username);
    }

    /**
     * Runs the post form procedure.
     */
    private function run() {
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            $this->readFormParameters();
            try {
                $this->validate();
                $this->save();
            }
            catch (\Exception $e) {
                $error = '<div id="error" style="font-size:16px; font-family: \'Armata\';">Error: '
                    . $this->errorText .'</div>';
                // where should error be displayed?
            }
        }
    }
}
new LoginForm();
```

Here the LoginDatabase.class.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Manages the login procedure.
 * 
 * @author      Jim Martens
 * @copyright   2013 Jim Martens
 * @license     http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-3.0 GNU Lesser General Public License, version 3
 */
class LoginDatabase {
    /**
     * Contains the mysqli object.
     * @var \mysqli
     */
    private $mysqli = null;

    /**
     * Contains the database table name.
     * @var string
     */
    private $table = 'users';

    /**
     * Contains the users.
     * @var array
     */
    private $users = array();

    /**
     * Contains the userIDs mapped to the respective names.
     * @var integer[]
     */
    private $userIDsToName = array();

    /**
     * Initializes the login database.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        include('dbconfig.inc.php');
        $this->mysqli = new \mysqli($host, $dbUser, $dbPwd, $dbName);
        if ($this->mysqli->connect_error) {
            die('Connect Error (' . $this->mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
                . $this->mysqli->connect_error);
        }

        $this->cacheQuery();
    }

    /**
     * Closes the connection.
     */
    public function __destruct() {
        $this->mysqli->close();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the userID for an existing user.
     * 
     * @param   string  $username
     * @return  integer
     * 
     * @require userExists($username)
     */
    public function getUserID($username) {
        $username = trim($username);
        return $this->userIDsToName[$username];
    }

    /**
     * Checks if a user exists.
     * 
     * @param   string  $username
     * @return  boolean
     */
    public function userExists($username) {
        $username = trim($username);
        $userExists = false;
        foreach ($this->users as $userID => $user) {
            if ($user['username'] == $username) {
                $userExists = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return $userExists;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if a user is active.
     * 
     * @param   string  $username
     * @return  boolean
     */
    public function userIsActive($username) {
        $username = trim($username);
        $isActive = $this->userExists($username);

        if ($isActive) {
            $userID = $this->userIDsToName[$username];
            $user = $this->users[$userID];
            $isActive = $user['isActive'];
        }

        return $isActive;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the login is valid.
     * 
     * @param   string  $username
     * @param   string  $password
     * @return  boolean
     */
    public function isLoginValid($username, $password) {
        $username = trim($username);
        $password = trim($password);

        $loginValid = $this->userIsActive($username);
        if ($loginValid) {
            $userID = $this->userIDsToName[$username];
            $user = $this->users[$userID];
            $salt = $user['salt'];
            $hashedPassword = sha1($password . sha1($password.$salt));
            $loginValid = ($hashedPassword == $user['password']);
        }

        return $loginValid;
    }

    /**
     * Reads all users from database.
     */
    private function cacheQuery() {
        $sql = 'SELECT uid, uname, password, salt, active
                FROM   '.$this->table;
        if ($result = $this->mysqli->query($sql, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {
            /* @var $result mysqli_result */
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc() !== NULL) {
                $row = array(
                    'userID' => intval($row['uid']),
                    'username' => $row['uname'],
                    'password' => $row['password'],
                    'salt' => $row['salt'],
                    'isActive' => (boolean) $row['active']
                );
                $this->users[$row['userID']] = $row;
                $this->userIDsToName[$row['username']] = $row['userID'];
            }

            $result->free();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx, i wrote your codes in one file to check them but i am getting fatal error and undefined variable.

Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\l\index.php on line 41

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\l\index.php on line 41

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right. I will update that answer with a more correct solution. That will use a class for the database functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too,

```
$username = sanitize($username);
$sql = "SELECT uid FROM users WHERE uname = '$username'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is outright attrocious code. All of the database operations are simply assuming nothing will EVER fail. This is a very very bad design. Databases and queries can fail all the time. As well, your code doesn't seem to ever actually CONNECT to the database, unless you simply haven't shown any of that code.

A far better, easier to debug version of one of your functions would be:

```
$username = sanitize($username);
$sql = "SELECT uid FROM users WHERE uname = '$username'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
   return false;
} else {
   return true;
}
```

This will properly handle database error, provide you with the actual query used for debugging if need be, and PROPERLY looks for a result, without assuming there will be one.

And of course, in the greater scheme of things, you should not be writing new code using the mysql_*() functions. They are obsoleted and deprecated. If you're just starting out, then pretend that mysql_*() doesn't exist anymore, and start using mysqli (note the `i`) or PDO instead.

Comment: This isn't really an answer but a long comment.

Comment: this worked but now showing me error that i need to activate my account which is already activated. i mean it is allowing me first row only, not other rows.